# What does CMake use on Linux to work/modify RPATH of binaries?

Tags: cmake

What does CMake use on Linux to work with/modify RPATH of binaries?

I need to know it to install missing packages.

Does anybody know?

Comment: ? Just run it and see what error messages come up.

Comment: @KamilCuk I updated question. CMake says nothing about missing system executable. But install script just deletes `moc`

Comment: Then are you asking XY question? Are you sure you care about what tools are used by CMake, not how to solve your installation problem?

Comment: @KamilCuk These questions correlate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is:

> What does CMake use on Linux to work/modify RPATH of binaries?

> file(RPATH_CHECK

`file` from [cmFileCommand.cxx calls cmSystemTools::CheckRPath](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Source/cmFileCommand.cxx#L1177) which calls [cmELF::getRPath](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Source/cmSystemTools.cxx#L3211) which calls [CMELFInternal::GetRPath](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Source/cmELF.cxx#L123) which calls [GetDynamicSectionString](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Source/cmELF.cxx#L553) which calls `cmELFInternal::LoadDynamicSection` which just `seekg` the file stream and reads from the stream in [cmELFInternal::Read](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Source/cmELF.cxx#L326) and then optionally inverts the endianess.

The [types are used](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Source/cmELF.cxx#L178) from [elf.h](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html).

> file(RPATH_CHANGE

Calls [cmSystemTools::ChangeRPath](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Source/cmFileCommand.cxx#L1011) which appends the RPATH together with existing one and calls [AdjustRPathELF](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Source/cmSystemTools.cxx#L2735) which calls `RemoveRPathELF` which [just fills RPATH part of DYNAMIC section with zeros](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Source/cmSystemTools.cxx#L3137) and [then uses standard `operator<<` to write new RPATH](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Source/cmSystemTools.cxx#L2641),

So: CMake uses file operations - `open` `write` `read`.

> what does CMake need to work with RPATH.

Nothing. Well, a working underlying storage file system and kernel.